# date is error when run zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl on Solaris

Tags: perl, dns, bind, solaris, zabbix

analyse `named.stats` file On Solaris 10, SunOS azalea 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490
perl version: v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int
BIND 9.9.5-P1, this dns has view zone!

When I ran  `zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl` script, the date in the first line  of the result file `zabbix_named.stats.txt`  is wrong.

Input file: **named.stats**

```
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1411256097)
++ Incoming Requests ++
           245677755 QUERY
                  11 IQUERY
                 131 NOTIFY
                   5 UPDATE
++ Incoming Queries ++
                   7 RESERVED0
           214646337 A
              195659 NS
              194834 CNAME
               67573 SOA
            11863353 PTR
                  13 HINFO
              311508 MX
               80961 TXT
            17684359 AAAA
              313197 SRV
                  35 NAPTR
                1026 A6
                 377 DS
                   2 NSEC
                  16 DNSKEY
                2658 SPF
                   6 AXFR
              317449 ANY
                  14 Others
++ Outgoing Queries ++
[View: GLU]
            97641561 A
              913138 NS
                1668 CNAME
                3496 SOA
              584400 PTR
              215941 MX
              222061 TXT
             8968008 AAAA
               10839 SRV
                  74 DS
                   1 DNSKEY
               11600 ANY
[View: Other]
[View: _bind]
++ Name Server Statistics ++
           245679139 IPv4 requests received
             6939549 requests with EDNS(0) received
               29010 requests with TSIG received
               56072 TCP requests received
             1735225 auth queries rejected
            50400546 recursive queries rejected
                   6 transfer requests rejected
           231559258 responses sent
               39867 truncated responses sent
             6886241 responses with EDNS(0) sent
               28879 responses with TSIG sent
           134630025 queries resulted in successful answer
             7564120 queries resulted in authoritative answer
           145275533 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
               33203 queries resulted in referral answer
             8608506 queries resulted in nxrrset
            26580073 queries resulted in SERVFAIL
             9569385 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
            86774948 queries caused recursion
            12879202 duplicate queries received
             1239821 queries dropped
            52135771 other query failures
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
                 130 IPv4 notifies received
                4114 IPv4 SOA queries sent
                  20 IPv4 AXFR requested
                  10 IPv4 IXFR requested
                  30 transfer requests succeeded
++ Resolver Statistics ++
[Common]
              223764 mismatch responses received
[View: GLU]
           108570571 IPv4 queries sent
            76450226 IPv4 responses received
              519727 NXDOMAIN received
              150555 SERVFAIL received
               50543 FORMERR received
              394845 other errors received
               64245 EDNS(0) query failures
             6679270 truncated responses received
               77150 lame delegations received
            39157947 query retries
            32176451 query timeouts
             2446839 IPv4 NS address fetches
              131398 IPv4 NS address fetch failed
               10663 queries with RTT < 10ms
            55311397 queries with RTT 10-100ms
            17022288 queries with RTT 100-500ms
             3465431 queries with RTT 500-800ms
              455258 queries with RTT 800-1600ms
               12639 queries with RTT > 1600ms
[View: Other]
[View: _bind]
++ Cache DB RRsets ++
[View: GLU (Cache: GLU)]
               20848 A
               28539 NS
                4810 CNAME
                   4 SOA
                 140 PTR
                   4 MX
                  18 TXT
                1523 AAAA
                   1 SRV
                 167 DS
                 774 RRSIG
                 423 NSEC
                   1 DNSKEY
                  20 !A
                   5 !TXT
                 314 !AAAA
                 237 NXDOMAIN
[View: Other (Cache: Other)]
[View: _bind (Cache: _bind)]
++ Socket I/O Statistics ++
           101917427 UDP/IPv4 sockets opened
             6679398 TCP/IPv4 sockets opened
           101934142 UDP/IPv4 sockets closed
             6736965 TCP/IPv4 sockets closed
               32659 UDP/IPv4 socket bind failures
                1614 TCP/IPv4 socket connect failures
           101889277 UDP/IPv4 connections established
             6417057 TCP/IPv4 connections established
                 622 TCP/IPv4 connection accept failures
               57536 TCP/IPv4 connections accepted
                   5 TCP/IPv4 send errors
              173008 UDP/IPv4 recv errors
               37707 TCP/IPv4 recv errors
++ Per Zone Query Statistics ++
[0.0.127.in-addr.arpa (view: GLU)]
                  27 queries resulted in successful answer
                 164 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 137 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[160.192.222.in-addr.arpa (view: GLU)]
                 141 queries resulted in successful answer
                 792 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 651 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[0.0.127.in-addr.arpa (view: Other)]
[160.192.222.in-addr.arpa (view: Other)]
               92115 queries resulted in successful answer
              106915 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 123 queries resulted in nxrrset
               14677 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[glu.edu.cn (view: Other)]
                   5 transfer requests rejected
             1764308 queries resulted in successful answer
             2849091 queries resulted in authoritative answer
              574347 queries resulted in nxrrset
              510456 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[version.bind (view: _bind)]
                 264 queries resulted in successful answer
                 264 queries resulted in authoritative answer
[hostname.bind (view: _bind)]
                   3 queries resulted in successful answer
                   3 queries resulted in authoritative answer
[authors.bind (view: _bind)]
[id.server (view: _bind)]
--- Statistics Dump --- (1411256097)
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1411256113)
++ Incoming Requests ++
           245678141 QUERY
                  11 IQUERY
                 131 NOTIFY
                   5 UPDATE
++ Incoming Queries ++
                   7 RESERVED0
           214646692 A
              195659 NS
              194834 CNAME
               67578 SOA
            11863360 PTR
                  13 HINFO
              311512 MX
               80961 TXT
            17684371 AAAA
              313199 SRV
                  35 NAPTR
                1026 A6
                 377 DS
                   2 NSEC
                  16 DNSKEY
                2658 SPF
                   6 AXFR
              317450 ANY
                  14 Others
++ Outgoing Queries ++
[View: GLU]
            97641832 A
              913147 NS
                1668 CNAME
                3496 SOA
              584400 PTR
              215944 MX
              222061 TXT
             8968013 AAAA
               10839 SRV
                  74 DS
                   1 DNSKEY
               11600 ANY
[View: Other]
[View: _bind]
++ Name Server Statistics ++
           245679525 IPv4 requests received
             6939573 requests with EDNS(0) received
               29010 requests with TSIG received
               56072 TCP requests received
             1735231 auth queries rejected
            50400606 recursive queries rejected
                   6 transfer requests rejected
           231559636 responses sent
               39867 truncated responses sent
             6886265 responses with EDNS(0) sent
               28879 responses with TSIG sent
           134630301 queries resulted in successful answer
             7564152 queries resulted in authoritative answer
           145275810 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
               33203 queries resulted in referral answer
             8608514 queries resulted in nxrrset
            26580076 queries resulted in SERVFAIL
             9569410 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
            86775072 queries caused recursion
            12879204 duplicate queries received
             1239821 queries dropped
            52135837 other query failures
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
                 130 IPv4 notifies received
                4114 IPv4 SOA queries sent
                  20 IPv4 AXFR requested
                  10 IPv4 IXFR requested
                  30 transfer requests succeeded
++ Resolver Statistics ++
[Common]
              223769 mismatch responses received
[View: GLU]
           108570859 IPv4 queries sent
            76450431 IPv4 responses received
              519730 NXDOMAIN received
              150555 SERVFAIL received
               50543 FORMERR received
              394845 other errors received
               64245 EDNS(0) query failures
             6679285 truncated responses received
               77150 lame delegations received
            39158038 query retries
            32176528 query timeouts
             2446848 IPv4 NS address fetches
              131398 IPv4 NS address fetch failed
               10663 queries with RTT < 10ms
            55311569 queries with RTT 10-100ms
            17022314 queries with RTT 100-500ms
             3465436 queries with RTT 500-800ms
              455260 queries with RTT 800-1600ms
               12639 queries with RTT > 1600ms
[View: Other]
[View: _bind]
++ Cache DB RRsets ++
[View: GLU (Cache: GLU)]
               20863 A
               28540 NS
                4848 CNAME
                   4 SOA
                 140 PTR
                   4 MX
                  18 TXT
                1523 AAAA
                   1 SRV
                 167 DS
                 774 RRSIG
                 423 NSEC
                   1 DNSKEY
                  20 !A
                   5 !TXT
                 307 !AAAA
                 240 NXDOMAIN
[View: Other (Cache: Other)]
[View: _bind (Cache: _bind)]
++ Socket I/O Statistics ++
           101917700 UDP/IPv4 sockets opened
             6679413 TCP/IPv4 sockets opened
           101934409 UDP/IPv4 sockets closed
             6736981 TCP/IPv4 sockets closed
               32659 UDP/IPv4 socket bind failures
                1614 TCP/IPv4 socket connect failures
           101889550 UDP/IPv4 connections established
             6417072 TCP/IPv4 connections established
                 622 TCP/IPv4 connection accept failures
               57537 TCP/IPv4 connections accepted
                   5 TCP/IPv4 send errors
              173008 UDP/IPv4 recv errors
               37707 TCP/IPv4 recv errors
++ Per Zone Query Statistics ++
[0.0.127.in-addr.arpa (view: GLU)]
                  27 queries resulted in successful answer
                 164 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 137 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[160.192.222.in-addr.arpa (view: GLU)]
                 141 queries resulted in successful answer
                 792 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 651 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[glu.edu.cn (view: GLU)]
              390933 queries resulted in successful answer
              485439 queries resulted in authoritative answer
               56638 queries resulted in nxrrset
               37870 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[0.0.127.in-addr.arpa (view: Other)]
[160.192.222.in-addr.arpa (view: Other)]
               92115 queries resulted in successful answer
              106915 queries resulted in authoritative answer
                 123 queries resulted in nxrrset
               14677 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[glu.edu.cn (view: Other)]
                   5 transfer requests rejected
             1764319 queries resulted in successful answer
             2849104 queries resulted in authoritative answer
              574349 queries resulted in nxrrset
              510456 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[GLU.cn (view: Other)]
                   1 transfer requests rejected
               63626 queries resulted in successful answer
              243178 queries resulted in authoritative answer
               42873 queries resulted in nxrrset
              136679 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
[version.bind (view: _bind)]
                 264 queries resulted in successful answer
                 264 queries resulted in authoritative answer
[hostname.bind (view: _bind)]
                   3 queries resulted in successful answer
                   3 queries resulted in authoritative answer
[authors.bind (view: _bind)]
[id.server (view: _bind)]
--- Statistics Dump --- (1411256113)
```

Output file: **/tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt**

```
date: 0 Thu Jan  1 08:00:00 1970
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_0.0.127.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:  137
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_0.0.127.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:      164
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_0.0.127.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer: 27
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__CERNET__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:    32er:   423
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:      651
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:  792
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:     141
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:     14678
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer: 106920
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_nxrrset:      124
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_160.192.222.in-addr.arpa__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:    92118
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:   37890
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:       485515
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_nxrrset:    56662
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__GLU__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:  390965
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:  510477
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:      2849383
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_nxrrset:   574397
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__Other__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer: 1764529
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_glu.edu.cn__view__Other__transfer_requests_rejected:    5
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_hostname.bind__view___bind__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:    3
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_hostname.bind__view___bind__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:       3
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_version.bind__view___bind__queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:     266
Per_Zone_Query_Statistics_Zone_version.bind__view___bind__queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:        266
```

zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl (from https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=38970):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Dmitry Maksimov 5.02.2013 dima_dm@hotmail.com
# bind 9.6.X and high statistics for Zabbix
#######
# Need!!! perl-suidperl-5.8.5-36.el4_6.3.i386.rpm or later
# Permissions on script
# chmod 4755 zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl
# ls -l zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl
# -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 2876 Feb  5 17:40 zabbix_bind.9.6_stats.pl
# Per Zone Query Statistics via Zabbix  Low Level Descovery (LLD) (bind option zone-statistics yes) which is only available in Zabbix 2.0 and high.
#### Config ######
my $rndc  = '/usr/local/bind9/sbin/rndc';
my $retry = 3;                              # if error
my $sleep = 5;                              # in sec
my $data  = 10000;                          # in bytes, size of one statictics sample
my $maxsize
    = 5000000;    # in bytes $stats file maximum size. If size of file more, whis file ($stats) will be cleared.
my $stats     = '/var/named/named.stats';
my $stat_file = '/tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt';
#### End Config ###
#### Error Code ####
# 1 - OK
# 2 - Error
####################
my $i;
my $date      = 0;
my $flag      = 0;
my $stat_name = "";
my $zone      = "";
my $text      = "";
my $counter   = "";
my $view      = "";
my $code      = 1;
my %RESULT    = ();
my %ZONENAME  = ();
delete @ENV{qw(IFS CDPATH ENV BASH_ENV)};    # Make %ENV safer
$ENV{'PATH'} = "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin";

while ( $code > 0 && $i < $retry ) {
    $i++;
    $code = system("$rndc stats");
    if ( $code > 0 ) { sleep($sleep); }
}
my $position = ( stat($stats) )[7];
if ( $position < $data ) {
    $position = 0;
} else {
    $position = $position - $data;
}

open( FILE, "$stats" );
seek( FILE, $position, 0 );
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/^\+{3} Statistics Dump \+{3}\s+\((\d+)\)/) { $date = $1; $flag = 1; %RESULT = (); }
    if (/^--- Statistics Dump ---/)                 { $flag = 0; }
    if (/^\+{2}\s+(.*)?\s+(?=\+{2})/) {
        $stat_name = $1;
        $view      = "";
        if ( $stat_name eq "Per Zone Query Statistics" ) { $flag = 2; $zone = ""; }
    }
    if (/^\[View:\s+(.*)?(?=\])/) { $view = "_View_" . $1; }
    if ( /^\[(.*)?(?=\])/ && $flag == 2 ) { $zone = "_Zone_" . $1; $zone =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]#_#g; }
    if ( /^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)?(?=\n)/ && $flag == 1 ) {
        $text    = $stat_name . $view . "_" . $2;
        $counter = $1;
        $text =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]#_#g;
        $RESULT{$text} = $counter;
    }
    if ( /^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)?(?=\n)/ && $flag == 2 ) {
        $text    = $stat_name . $zone . "_" . $2;
        $counter = $1;
        $text =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]#_#g;
        $RESULT{$text}   = $counter;
        $ZONENAME{$zone} = 1;
    }
}
close(FILE);
if ( ( stat($stats) )[7] > $maxsize ) {
    open( FILE, ">$stats" );
    close(FILE);
}
open( FILE, ">$stat_file" );
print FILE "date: $date ", scalar( localtime($date) ), "\n";
foreach $i ( sort( keys %RESULT ) ) {
    print FILE "$i:\t$RESULT{$i}\n";
}
close(FILE);
if ( defined( $ARGV[0] ) && lc( $ARGV[0] ) eq "lld" ) {
    print_lld();
} else {
    if ( $code > 0 ) {
        print "2\n";
    } else {
        print "1\n";
    }
}

sub print_lld {
    my $first = 1;
    my $key   = "";

    print "{\n";
    print "\t\"data\":[\n\n";

    foreach $key ( keys %ZONENAME ) {
        print "\t,\n" if not $first;
        $first = 0;
        print "\t{\n";
        print "\t\t\"{#ZONENAME}\":\"$key\"\n";
        print "\t}\n";
    }

    print "\n\t]\n";
    print "}\n";
}
```

---

**When I run it in Other machince, Date value is ok!**

This machince: SunOS orchid 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-4
perl version: v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int
BIND 9.9.5-P1, But this dns has not view zone!

Input file: **named.stats**

```
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1411352600)
++ Incoming Requests ++
              331205 QUERY
++ Incoming Queries ++
              174193 A
                1045 NS
                 103 CNAME
                 760 SOA
              103046 PTR
                 276 MX
                  18 TXT
               41567 AAAA
                  49 SRV
                 286 A6
                   2 NSEC
                9863 ANY
++ Outgoing Queries ++
[View: default]
              190903 A
                1443 NS
                 971 PTR
                1225 AAAA
                  24 SRV
[View: _bind]
++ Name Server Statistics ++
              331207 IPv4 requests received
              177845 requests with EDNS(0) received
                  23 TCP requests received
               38595 auth queries rejected
                2468 recursive queries rejected
              330359 responses sent
                  27 truncated responses sent
              177847 responses with EDNS(0) sent
              227691 queries resulted in successful answer
              197399 queries resulted in authoritative answer
               91628 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
               41394 queries resulted in nxrrset
                 267 queries resulted in SERVFAIL
               19942 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
               78029 queries caused recursion
                 851 duplicate queries received
               41063 other query failures
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
                 513 IPv4 SOA queries sent
++ Resolver Statistics ++
[Common]
[View: default]
              194568 IPv4 queries sent
              188556 IPv4 responses received
                1113 NXDOMAIN received
                  91 SERVFAIL received
                 863 FORMERR received
                  30 other errors received
                 877 EDNS(0) query failures
                 274 truncated responses received
                 200 lame delegations received
               16212 query retries
                6142 query timeouts
               28491 IPv4 NS address fetches
                  84 IPv4 NS address fetch failed
                 111 queries with RTT < 10ms
              144059 queries with RTT 10-100ms
               44047 queries with RTT 100-500ms
                 250 queries with RTT 500-800ms
                   3 queries with RTT 800-1600ms
[View: _bind]
++ Cache DB RRsets ++
[View: default]
                1087 A
                 583 NS
                 191 CNAME
                   1 PTR
                 174 AAAA
                  21 DS
                  74 RRSIG
                  17 NSEC
                   1 !A
                   2 NXDOMAIN
[View: _bind (Cache: _bind)]
++ Socket I/O Statistics ++
              194826 UDP/IPv4 sockets opened
                 277 TCP/IPv4 sockets opened
              194826 UDP/IPv4 sockets closed
                 298 TCP/IPv4 sockets closed
                  19 UDP/IPv4 socket bind failures
              194291 UDP/IPv4 connections established
                  48 TCP/IPv4 connections established
                  25 TCP/IPv4 connections accepted
                  87 UDP/IPv4 recv errors
++ Per Zone Query Statistics ++
--- Statistics Dump --- (1411352600)
```

Output file: **/tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt**

```
date: 1411352600 Mon Sep 22 10:23:20 2014
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_A: 1087
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_AAAA:      174
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_CNAME:     191
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_DS:        21
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_NS:        583
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_NSEC:      17
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_NXDOMAIN:  2
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_PTR:       1
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default_RRSIG:     74
Cache_DB_RRsets_View_default__A:        1
Incoming_Queries_A:     174193
Incoming_Queries_A6:    286
Incoming_Queries_AAAA:  41567
Incoming_Queries_ANY:   9863
Incoming_Queries_CNAME: 103
Incoming_Queries_MX:    276
Incoming_Queries_NS:    1045
Incoming_Queries_NSEC:  2
Incoming_Queries_PTR:   103046
Incoming_Queries_SOA:   760
Incoming_Queries_SRV:   49
Incoming_Queries_TXT:   18
Incoming_Requests_QUERY:        331205
Name_Server_Statistics_IPv4_requests_received:  331207
Name_Server_Statistics_TCP_requests_received:   23
Name_Server_Statistics_auth_queries_rejected:   38595
Name_Server_Statistics_duplicate_queries_received:      851
Name_Server_Statistics_other_query_failures:    41063
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_caused_recursion:        78029
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_NXDOMAIN:    19942
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_SERVFAIL:    267
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_authoritative_answer:        197399
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_non_authoritative_answer:    91628
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_nxrrset:     41394
Name_Server_Statistics_queries_resulted_in_successful_answer:   227691
Name_Server_Statistics_recursive_queries_rejected:      2468
Name_Server_Statistics_requests_with_EDNS_0__received:  177845
Name_Server_Statistics_responses_sent:  330359
Name_Server_Statistics_responses_with_EDNS_0__sent:     177847
Name_Server_Statistics_truncated_responses_sent:        27
Outgoing_Queries_View_default_A:        190903
Outgoing_Queries_View_default_AAAA:     1225
Outgoing_Queries_View_default_NS:       1443
Outgoing_Queries_View_default_PTR:      971
Outgoing_Queries_View_default_SRV:      24
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_EDNS_0__query_failures:        877
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_FORMERR_received:      863
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_IPv4_NS_address_fetch_failed:  84
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_IPv4_NS_address_fetches:       28491
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_IPv4_queries_sent:     194568
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_IPv4_responses_received:       188556
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_NXDOMAIN_received:     1113
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_SERVFAIL_received:     91
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_lame_delegations_received:     200
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_other_errors_received: 30
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_queries_with_RTT_10-100ms:     144059
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_queries_with_RTT_100-500ms:    44047
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_queries_with_RTT_500-800ms:    250
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_queries_with_RTT_800-1600ms:   3
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_queries_with_RTT___10ms:       111
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_query_retries: 16212
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_query_timeouts:        6142
Resolver_Statistics_View_default_truncated_responses_received:  274
Socket_I_O_Statistics_TCP_IPv4_connections_accepted:    25
Socket_I_O_Statistics_TCP_IPv4_connections_established: 48
Socket_I_O_Statistics_TCP_IPv4_sockets_closed:  298
Socket_I_O_Statistics_TCP_IPv4_sockets_opened:  277
Socket_I_O_Statistics_UDP_IPv4_connections_established: 194291
Socket_I_O_Statistics_UDP_IPv4_recv_errors:     87
Socket_I_O_Statistics_UDP_IPv4_socket_bind_failures:    19
Socket_I_O_Statistics_UDP_IPv4_sockets_closed:  194826
Socket_I_O_Statistics_UDP_IPv4_sockets_opened:  194826
Zone_Maintenance_Statistics_IPv4_SOA_queries_sent:      513
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the script answer my question in zabbix forum:

```
that size оf one statistics sample < $data in Byte.
my $data=10000
```

I set to my $data  >  size оf named.stats.

It works fine.

thinks!

Answer (score 0):

The date in the output file is set to `0` initially, and then gets parsed from `named.stats` in this line of the script:

```
if (/^\+{3} Statistics Dump \+{3}\s+\((\d+)\)/) { $date = $1; $flag = 1; %RESULT = (); }
```

The date and time are recorded in `named.stats` in Unix time, the number of seconds after Jan 1st 1970.

If, for some reason, that line of the stats file does not match this expression, the date will not get set, and the script will assume that the date/time *is* 0, i.e. that it's Jan 1st 1970.

You will need to work out why the script is not finding the date correctly. Was `named.stats` available when the script ran? Did the script give any errors? Has your system clock stopped working so it thinks it's Jan 1st 1970 all the time? Etc.

If you add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of the script (under the first line), this will enable warnings which will make it easier to track down errors.

Comment: return 1 when the script ran.  I added " use strict; use warnings; " to the script.  run it, it display: Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at ./bind9_stats.pl line 39.      line 39 is "while ($code>0 && $i<$retry)"

Comment: Did the output file have the correct date in it, and does the current `named.stats` file have a long number in the first line (e.g. +++ Statistics Dump +++ (12387128472) )?

Comment: Yes, The **input file named.stats**  have a long number in the first line (e.g. +++ Statistics Dump +++ (12387128472) ).  The **output file /tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt** the first line is `date: 0 Thu Jan  1 08:00:00 1970`

Comment: What is the creation date of /tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt? Has it definitely just been created by the script?

Comment: I has added all contents of the input file named.stats to the question. The creation date of /tmp/zabbix_named.stats.txt is:  `-rw-rw-r--   1 root     zabbix      8561 Sep 21 07:37 zabbix_named.stats.txt`

Comment: I get different results when I run the script on the data you posted above. Has this script worked in the past or is this the first time you've run it?

Comment: I run it first time. My OS: **SunOS azalea 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490**, Perl version: **This is perl, v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int**